# How to write one-line ternary expressions using `is None` in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am interested in using one-line ternary expressions instead of traditional multiline `if-else` blocks.  However, expressions comparing `is None` give different results.

Here is an example comparing *multiline* and *one-line* variants of **two forms** of a conditional expression for a predicate:

1. `if pred is not None`
2. `if pred is None`

**Code**

```
import operator as op


# First form
def is_not_none_multiline(a, b, pred=None):
    if pred is not None:
        predicate = pred
    else:
        predicate = lambda x, y: x + y
    return predicate(a, b)

def is_not_none_oneline(a, b, pred=None):
    predicate = pred if pred is not None else lambda x, y: x + y
    return predicate(a, b)

# Second Form
def is_none_multiline(a, b, pred=None):
    if pred is None:
        predicate = lambda x, y: x + y
    else:
        predicate = pred
    return predicate(a, b)

def is_none_oneline(a, b, pred=None):
    predicate = lambda x, y: x + y if pred is None else pred
    return predicate(a, b)
```

**Tests**

Here are tests for optional arguments in mutliline and one-line variants.  The final result was unexpected:

```
assert is_not_none_multiline(1, 2) == 3
assert is_not_none_oneline(1, 2) == 3
assert is_not_none_multiline(1, 2, pred=op.mul) == 2
assert is_not_none_oneline(1, 2, pred=op.mul) == 2

assert is_none_multiline(1, 2) == 3
assert is_none_oneline(1, 2) == 3
assert is_none_multiline(1, 2, pred=op.mul) == 2
assert is_none_oneline(1, 2, pred=op.mul) == 2

# ----> 4 assert is_none_oneline(1, 2, pred=op.mul) == 2
# AssertionError:
```

Although `pred is not None` works as one-line:

```
predicate = pred if pred is not None else lambda x, y: x + y
```

`pred is None` does not work as one-line:

```
predicate = lambda x, y: x + y if pred is None else pred
```

**Details**

Apparantly, the `pred` function is not evaluated when passed in as a keyword to `is_none_oneline()`. Rather, it is returned:

```
print(is_none_oneline(1, 2, pred=op.mul))
# <built-in function mul>
```

This analysis was verified in a Python Tutor visualization when executing both variants of the *second form* (see visualizations here [`is not None` multiline](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20is_not_none_multiline%28a,%20b,%20pred%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20pred%20is%20not%20None%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20predicate%20%3D%20pred%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20predicate%20%3D%20lambda%20x,%20y%3A%20x%20%2B%20y%0A%20%20%20%20return%20predicate%28a,%20b%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28is_not_none_multiline%281,%202%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=9&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), [`is not None` one-line](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20operator%20as%20op%0A%0A%0Adef%20is_not_none_oneliner%28a,%20b,%20pred%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20predicate%20%3D%20pred%20if%20pred%20is%20not%20None%20else%20lambda%20x,%20y%3A%20x%20%2B%20y%0A%20%20%20%20return%20predicate%28a,%20b%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28is_not_none_oneliner%281,%202,%20pred%3Dop.mul%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), [`is None` multiline](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20operator%20as%20op%0A%0A%0Adef%20is_none_multi%28a,%20b,%20pred%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20pred%20is%20None%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20predicate%20%3D%20lambda%20x,%20y%3A%20x%20%2B%20y%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20predicate%20%3D%20pred%0A%20%20%20%20return%20predicate%28a,%20b%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28is_none_multi%281,%202,%20pred%3Dop.mul%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), [`is None` one-line](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20operator%20as%20op%0A%0A%0Adef%20is_none_oneliner%28a,%20b,%20pred%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20predicate%20%3D%20lambda%20x,%20y%3A%20x%20%2B%20y%20if%20pred%20is%20None%20else%20pred%0A%20%20%20%20return%20predicate%28a,%20b%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28is_none_oneliner%281,%202,%20pred%3Dop.mul%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)).

**Questions**

It is unclear why an equivalent ternary expression returns a function rather than a computed value.

1. Can someone explain why the predicate is not evaluated in the second form - a one-line, `pred is None` expression?
2. How does one correctly write `pred is None` in one-line?

Comment: This question demonstrates why one-liners show be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a simple case of operator precedence.

You're getting a callable which returns a callable.  I think you wanted this instead, to make sure the conditional gets grouped the other way:

```
def is_none_oneline(a, b, pred=None):
    predicate = (lambda x, y: x + y) if pred is None else pred
    return predicate(a, b)
```

Comment: And if the `lambda` is in the `else`, as in the `not None` test, then the parse is unambiguous.

Comment: @pylang  It was being grouped `lambda x, y: (x + y if pred is None else pred)`.  To avoid these confusions in future: 1. resist the urge to one-liner everything.   2. Don't assign lambda functions to names.  If they need a name, they should not be a lambda.